# How to display value of the variable and symbol '$' in the one label?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In my program on the **WindowsForms** (VS13) I have a label, which contains a value of the variable:

```
label6.Text = indicators.money.ToString();
```

When I'm doing like this, I'm getting a value of the  variable **money** on the screen: **50**. But i need to display it like **50$**. How to do that without adding one more label?

Comment: `label6.Text = indicators.money.ToString() + "$";`

Comment: `indicators.money.ToString("C");`

Comment: Note that Habib's approach here will use the current culture to determine not only the appropriate currency symbol, but also how/where to display it.

Comment: @Habib: You should post this as an answer. This enables the OP to mark this question as answered (check mark). You are right, usually this would be just a comment; however nobody posted an answer until now. And you could integrate the comments of Jon Skeet into the answer.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, just added an answer and made it a community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net framework provides a way for showing currency sign with monetary values.

For your case you can do:

```
label6.Text = indicators.money.ToString("C");
```

But as [Jon Skeet has pointed out in commen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431923/how-to-display-value-of-the-variable-and-symbol-in-the-one-label?noredirect=1#comment35911743_23431923)t:

> approach here will use the current culture to determine not only the
>   appropriate currency symbol, but also how/where to display it.

So, if your culture is `en-US` you will get the currency sign before the value like:

```
$23.25
```

You can change that for the culture using properties: [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx) and [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx). Like:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 1;
decimal money = 23.25M;
string str = money.ToString("C", ci);
```

then you will get:

```
"23.25$"
```

`CurrencyPositivePatter` expects an int value which determines the position of currency symbol, For `en-US` culture it would be like:

```
0      $n
1      n$
2      $ n //(with a space)
3      n $ //(with a space)
```

You may see: [Standard Numeric Format Strings - Currency Format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString)

> The "C" (or currency) format specifier converts a number to a string
>   that represents a currency amount. The precision specifier indicates
>   the desired number of decimal places in the result string. If the
>   precision specifier is omitted, the default precision is defined by
>   the NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits property.